# Incorrect result for some values when creating a subclass Triangle in Java that computes area and perimeter

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I have an assignment that asks me to create a subclass Triangle that extends  GeometricObject. I'm very close to getting the solution correct, but there's a problem with my perimeter method. The problem I'm having is that my program is computing the correct perimeter at times and at times computes the perimeter using the initial 1.0 value for all 3 sides.

**This is the instructions:** 
The Triangle Class: Your code folder contains a class named GeometricObject. Without modifying this class in any way, extend it to create a new class named Triangle.

The Triangle class contains:

- a single field named sides that consists of an array of three double values, representing side1, side2, and side3. You must use an array; do not use individual instance variables. Each element should have default values of 1.0 to represent the three sides of the triangle.
- a no-arg constructor that creates a default Triangle: (new Triangle()).
- a constructor that creates a Triangle with the three sides specified: (new Triangle(1.0, 2.0, 1.5)).
- a third constructor that takes the three sides, the Color and whether or not the object should be filled: (new Triangle(1.0, 2.0, 1.5, Color.RED, true)).
- A method named getArea() that returns the area of the Triangle. (Look up the formula online, using Heron's formula.)
- A method named getPerimeter().
- A method named toString() that returns a String description of the Triangle.

**This is what I've worked on so far (my code):**

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject
{
    private double side1 = 1.0;
    private double side2  = 1.0; 
    private double side3  = 1.0; 
    //no args constructor.
    public Triangle ()
    {
    }
     public Triangle (double side1, double side2, double side3)
    {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        double s = ( side1 + side2 + side3 ) / 2.0 ; 
        double area = Math.sqrt ( s * ( s - side1) * (s - side2 ) * (s - side3)); 
        return area; 
    }
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return (side1 + side2 + side3);
    }
      public Triangle ( double side1 , double side2 , double side3 ,Color color, boolean statement )
    {
    }
    public String toString()
    {       
        return ( "t1.getArea() = " + getArea() + "\nt1.getPerimeter() = " + 
                getPerimeter() + "\nTriangle: side1 = " + 
            side1 + ", side2 = " + side2 + ", side3 = " + side3) ;
    }   

}
```

**This is what I get from checking the Test Program:**

### Testing Triangle

- Class Triangle is defined (0.5)
- Class Triangle is public (0.5)
- Class Triangle extends GeometricObject (0.5)
- Three constructors are defined. (0.5)
- Default (no-arg) constructor defined. (1.0)
- Triangle(double, double, double) constructor defined. (3.0)
- Triangle(double, double, double, Color, boolean) constructor is defined. (1.0)
- Correct perimeter for simple triangle. (3.0)
- Correct area for simple triangle. (3.0)
- Correct perimeter for 3-arg triangle with sides 5.39, 3.56, 8.44 (2.0)
- Correct area for 3-arg triangle with sides 10.82, 4.36, 10.47 (2.0)
- Correct perimeter for 3-arg triangle with sides 8.41, 7.65, 9.8 (2.0)
- Correct area for 3-arg triangle with sides 2.63, 4.51, 1.41 (2.0)
  X Incorrect perimeter for 3-arg triangle with sides 6.17, 9.03, 1.64
  expected:<16.84> but was:<3.0> (2.0)
  X Incorrect perimeter for 3-arg triangle with sides 2.48, 1.86, 2.08
  expected:<6.42> but was:<3.0> (2.0)
- Correct toString for 3-arg triangle with sides 4.66, 7.65, 1.83 (3.0)--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  86% (24.0/28.0 tests passing)

**This the code for GeometricObject:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Date;
public class GeometricObject
{
    private Color color = Color.WHITE;
    private boolean filled;
    private Date dateCreated;

    /** 
     * Construct a default geometric object.
     */
    public GeometricObject()
    {
        dateCreated = new Date(); // System time.
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a GeometricObject with a given color and filled state.
     * @param color the initial color of the object
     * @param filled whether the object is filled
     */
    public GeometricObject(Color color, boolean filled)
    {
        this(); // set the date
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    /** 
     * Return current color.
     * @return current color.
     */
    public Color getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * Return true if the object is filled.
     * @return true if the object is filled. 
     */
    public boolean isFilled()
    {
        return filled;
    }

    /** 
     * Set a new filled value. 
     * @param filled the new filled value.
     */
    public void setFilled(boolean filled)
    {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    /** 
     * Get dateCreated.
     * @return the date the object was created.
     */
    public Date getDateCreated()
    {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    /** 
     * Return a string representation of this object.
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return "created on " + dateCreated + "\ncolor: " + color
            + " and filled: " + filled;
    }
}
```

I know this is a long post and I'll would really appreciate your help and thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Hi, where exactly are you facing problem? and can you give examples of given input and expected output?

Comment: You do not defined any code for your 5 parameter constructor - that is why you are getting the default values

Comment: You have an empty constructor `public Triangle ( double side1 , double side2 , double side3 ,Color color, boolean statement )
    {
    }` With the  computation errors you get (`was:<3.0>`) I suppose you invoke it instead of the no empty  constructor.

Comment: Please reduce this question to a [mcve] - I suspect that in doing so, you'll find the problem that other commenters have already referred to.

Comment: I know the test output _says_ it's calling the 3-arg constructor, but it almost certainly isn't.  For the cases that have failed, it seems to have called the 5-arg constructor.  So to make it work, you'd better write some code in the 5-arg constructor.

Comment: Ah. Yes, the problem does lie with my empty constructor. I'm currently writing the code for it and the test result does not talk about an error with the perimeter anymore. The only problem I have is that there's no method in GeometricObject to fill the Triangle with color..

Comment: That's OK, because you can use the `super` keyword to make the 5-arg `Triangle` constructor call the 2-arg `GeometricObject` constructor.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yes, I figured the problem out. I was able to call the 2 arg constructor on the GeometricOjbect using `super(color, filled);` and was able to complete my code.

Comment: @Vickie well done - I'm glad you got it all working.  Good luck with your ongoing learning.